# How to play all local videos consecutively

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avfoundation, avplayer

My app plays 5 short videos (stored in the app) by tapping 5 different buttons. I would like to have a "Play all"-button that plays all videos consecutively.

Here's my code for playing one video:

```
-(IBAction)playVideo1;
{
NSURL *videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@”video1” withExtension:@"mp4"];

AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];

AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
controller.player = player;
[player play];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

controller.view.frame = self.view.frame;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:_currentItem];
}
```

Comment: refer this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avqueueplayer

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVFoundationQueuePlayer-iOS/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thank you @karthikeyan. But that was a bit too advanced for me. I'm a beginner at this. Do you think you can help me with a specific code?

Comment: Go through this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the answer myself thanks to the provided links and some googleing.

Here's how to play the videos in sequence using AVQueuePlayer:

```
- (IBAction)playAll:(id)sender {
NSString *firstVideoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@”video1” ofType:@"m4v"];
NSString *secondVideoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video2” ofType:@"m4v"];
NSString *thirdVideoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video3” ofType:@"m4v"];
NSString *fourthVideoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video4” ofType:@"m4v"];
NSString *fifthVideoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video5” ofType:@"m4v"];    

AVPlayerItem *firstVideoItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:firstVideoPath]];
AVPlayerItem *secondVideoItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:secondVideoPath]];
AVPlayerItem *thirdVideoItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:thirdVideoPath]];
AVPlayerItem *fourthVideoItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fourthVideoPath]];
AVPlayerItem *fifthVideoItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fifthVideoPath]];

queuePlayer = [AVQueuePlayer queuePlayerWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstVideoItem, secondVideoItem, thirdVideoItem, fourthVideoItem, fifthVideoItem, nil]];

// create a player view controller
AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
controller.player = queuePlayer;
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
[queuePlayer play];
```